# What's the best way to update LINK fields with path of current document using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I have 4 documents, 3 excel spreadsheets and 1 document. All four are in the same directory "test." All four will always remain in the same directory no matter what. However, the goal of the document is to build a report out of the three spreadsheets for multiple properties. This means that the paths would be different for every different computer that it was used on. I want a macro that will auto-update the LINK fields with the current path but I'm running into some trouble.

So far I have

```
SendKeys "%{F9}"
Dim path As String
path = ActiveDocument.path
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
.Text = "C:\\Users\\Gianni\\Desktop"
.Replacement.Text = path
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
SendKeys "%{F9}"
```

There are two problems with this from what I can tell. If I just view the fields manually and run the code without the first SendKeys command, the find & replace works. With the first SendKeys command, however, the code doesn't replace the text with the new path. Still, the path that pastes ends up breaking the link anyway. How do I go about fixing these?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your second problem. It sounds like some `Find/Replace` is happening, but you're getting a path that breaks the links. What is the new path and how is it different from the desired path?

Comment: Well the original link would look like "C:\\Users\\Gianni\\Desktop" but the path given by ActiveDocument.path gives it "C:\Users\Gianni\Desktop" which Word doesn't recognize as a field LINK.

Comment: I notice that on Windows the path in the link uses two backslashes \\ as the delimiter, while `ActiveDocument.Path` uses one \. Maybe you need to  modify the path string before doing the Find/Replace.

Comment: @xidgel how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use vba’s Replace function. I’m away from my PC but it should add a line of code something like path = Replace(path, “\”,  “\\”)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, it's better in Word to work with the underlying object model of a Word document, than trying to reproduce exactly what you do as a user. Understanding how Word works, from a user point-of-view is very important and there are many things you you're able to do by converting those steps into a macro. But digging into the object model is generally faster and more accurate.

Changing a LINK field code is one of those things - and like many things, there's more than one way to go about it. Here are two possibilities.

The first is close to how you're approaching it, by manipulating the field code. Note that it's not necessary, using VBA, to actually *display* the field code. The object model lets you manipulate it "behind the scenes".

This procedure loops all the Fields in the document, checks whether each is a LINK field. If it is, the alternate path is substituted in the field code for the original path using the VBA `Replace` function, then this is written to the field code.

```
'Assumes the linked Excel workbook is an inline shape
Sub ChangePathInLinkField()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim fld As word.Field
    Dim strSearchPath As String
    Dim strReplacePath As String
    Dim strNewFieldCode As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    strSearchPath = "C:\\Users\\[user name]\\Documents\\SampleChart.xlsx"
    strReplacePath = "C:\\Test\\SampleChart.xlsx"
    For Each fld In doc.Fields
      If fld.Type = wdFieldLink Then
        strNewFieldCode = Replace(fld.code.Text, strSearchPath, strReplacePath)
        fld.code.Text = strNewFieldCode
      End If
    Next
    doc.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

The second procedure shows how the link path can be changed for Shapes as well as InlineShapes (if you have a Shape you can't see the LINK field). It can also be used only on InlineShapes, of course. This loops the collection, checks whether the object is a linked OLE object and, if it is, changes the path.

Which one to use will depend on your situation - test them both and decide based on that.

```
'Alternate: works with OLE object
Sub ChangePathInLinkedObject()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim ils As word.InlineShape
    Dim shp As word.Shape
    Dim strReplacePath As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    strReplacePath = "C:\Users\Cindy Meister\Documents\SampleChart.xlsx"
    strReplacePath = "C:\Test\SampleChart.xlsx"
    'For Each doesn't work because updating the field
    'destroys the object, so it loops over the same object
    'For this reason it's also necessary to work backwards through the document
    For i = doc.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set ils = doc.InlineShapes(i)
        If ils.Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedOLEObject Then
            ils.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = strReplacePath
            ils.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next

    For i = doc.shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set shp = doc.shapes(i)
        If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = strReplacePath
            shp.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Another question if I may; would it be possible to set the find and replace variable to whatever the new variable is so that next time the macro runs it now looks for the new path instead of the same path from the first find and replace?

Comment: If you don't mind, it would be better for you to finish this question (mark one of the answers as The Answer by clicking the checkmark to the left and up-voting any of them you find useful) and post the follow-up as a new question. It's an important/interesting point and it would be shame for it to be "buried" down in these comments. In that way, others can find and profit from it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `SendKeys` you can show field codes with:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
```

and to show field values

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
```

That *may* help with your first problem.

Answer (score -1):

To see how to implement relative paths in Word, check out the solution I've posted at:
http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154379-Word-Fields-and-Relative-Paths-to-External-Files
Since you're working with LINK fields, you'll need the macro solution there.

Comment: Quote from the StackOverflow FAQ in [help] about answering questions: Provide context for links - Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.